# Find all Eulerian cycles in a directed graph

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal, eulerian-paths

I am trying to create an algorithm that can find all Eulerian cycles in a directed graph. I was able to make an algorithm that can find one cycle in the graph, but I don't know how to find all the cycles. Searching around I found that I had to use [BEST theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEST_theorem) somehow.

```
def eulerian_cycle_from(graph: Dict[str, List[str]], path: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    """Generate a new cycle from the tip of the path.

    This function will add all possible circles still in the graph it can find
    from nodes in the path to the path and return the path.
    Calling itself with smaller an increasingly smaller graph
    """

    node = path.pop()
    edges = graph[node]

    backtrack = []

    # Follow path
    while edges:
        path.append(node)
        node = edges.pop()
        edges = graph[node]

    # Backtrack to see if there is still a node with edges in current path.
    while True:
        graph.pop(node, None)
        backtrack.append(node)

        if not path:  # We completed cycle, could not find more free edges.
            return backtrack[::-1]

        node = path.pop()

        if graph.get(node):  # This node still has edges.
            # Augment path with a cycle from that node and add the backtrack
            path = eulerian_cycle_from(graph, path + [node])
            return path + backtrack[::-1]
```

Comment: If you want to enumerate all of them, this can take exponentially long, so it won't be efficient.  However, if you know how to prove the BEST theorem, presumably the proof is likely to implicitly contain such an enumeration.  If you want to count them, the BEST theorem presumably already tells you what you need to know.